# Using if statement to detect if SKSpriteNode left the screen but its x axis value is between screen width bounds

Tags: swift, if-statement, skspritenode

I have been trying to work out a way to detect if a **SKSpriteNode** left the screen but its **x** **axis** **value** is between **screen** **width** **bounds**. I came up with this (with a bit of help from this great community!).

```
override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {
    super.update(currentTime)

if (node.position.y < node.size.height && node.position.x > self.frame.size.width / 8 && node.position.x < self.frame.size.width - self.frame.size.width / 8){
testFunc()
}

}
```

Unfortunately I still seem to call this "testFunc" although the node was not between the screen bounds.

Just to make it clear, I need to detect this because in my function the node moves from the top of the screen to the bottom and I only want the function to be called if it reached the bottom and it was actually possible to see the node while going down the screen.

I would highly appreciate every helpful comment or answer!

### [Update]

The comments helped a lot!
This seems to work:

```
override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {
    super.update(currentTime)

if (node.position.y < 0 && node.position.x > self.frame.size.width - node.site.width && node.position.x < self.frame.size.width - node.self.width){
testFunc()
}

}
```

Probably the error was in the 
    self.frame.size.width / 8 
part as suggested

Comment: maybe your offsets (self.frame.size.width / 8) are too small? how big the node is?

Comment: I tried higher values but it still did not work :(

Comment: you can put `println(node.position)` in `update` method to trace the node's path. I bet it goes out of screen then when it is already below, it get back to your x-axis screen bounds and then testFunc is triggered.

Comment: Your arbitrary `width / 8` code smells a bit. Why not use the node's actual size to calculate the exact out-of-bounds position? Also, why are you checking if `node.position.y` is less than its size? Shouldn't you be comparing to the bounds origin?

Comment: Yeah you are somehow right, I will try to change that...